# Is there a way to add logic to Attributes in C# / Unity based on platform?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity project that has integration to google firebase, namely the firestore.  For iOS and android I'm using the sdk's from google which allows me to use some Firebase attributes on my fields to make reading and writing easier.

Attributes looks like, **[FirestoreData]** & **[FirestoreProperty]**

However, the SDK is not compatible with the webgl builds. I'd like to use the same classes for simplicity but the attributes mean it won't compile for webgl.

One solution, that I'm currently using, it just to duplicate the class sans attributes, e.g.

```
#if UNITY_WEBGL
public class SomeData
{
    public float height { get; set; }
    public float width { get; set; }
    public float depth { get; set; }
}
#else
[FirestoreData]
public class SomeData
{
    [FirestoreProperty] public float height { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty] public float width { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty] public float depth { get; set; }
}
#endif
```

but I wanted to know if there was a way to avoid this duplication.  Can you tell c# to ignore certain attributes with the directives? e.g.

```
[FirestoreProperty && !UNITY_WEBGL] public float depth { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hmmm.. not certain, but could you create your own custom attributes and then, in the logic for the custom attributes, either do nothing or fall down to the 'real' attribute method?

Comment: Putting attributes on the same line as the declaration is not very common in C#, but Unity projects tend to do it a lot. Move the attributes to separate lines and put `#if` on just the attribute on each property..

Comment: I have about a dozen classes that use the attributes and some have 40 or so fields, so adding in hundreds of #if and #endif on newlines seemed kind of messy, was wondering if there was a neater solution.

Comment: @Jonathan - I'm not sure how to write my own custom attributes if you could help me out there that would be great.  Would a custom attribute interfere with the Firestore attributes? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe in WebGL builds, you can supply your own dummy `FirestoreData` and `FirestoreProperty` attributes that don't do anything (and pull the reference to the assembly that provides them) so they get compiled just the same but don't trigger whatever functionality the real ones do.

Comment: @madreflection - genius!  Yes that works great, keeps the code nice and clean. 
 I'm adding answer below and thanks for the insight.

Comment: Would be good if you would have added that these attributes don't even exist in WebGL platform ;) I was under the expression when giving my answer they still exist but lead to undesired behavior ;)

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by adding my own custom attributes just for webgl that do nothing.  Fixes the compile error without having to add in hundreds of #if UNITY_WEBGL and #endif.   Two files, **FirestoreDataAttribute.cs** & **FirestorePropertyAttribute.cs**

```
#if UNITY_WEBGL
using System;

public class FirestoreDataAttribute : Attribute
{
}
#endif

#if UNITY_WEBGL
using System;
public class FirestorePropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
#endif
```

Thanks and credit to @madreflection for the idea. :)

Comment: Cool!  I'm glad that worked out.